# Example in Milnor's Morse theory book ,$f^{-1}[a,b]$ is not compact

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

I was reading Milnor's Morse theory book,in chapter three , there is a picture to illustrate the case that $f^{-1}[a,b]$ is not compact.

For the theorem that sublevel set diffeomorphic to each other if no critical point in between,and $f^{-1}[a,b]$ is compact.

there is a remark below which says :The condition that $f^{-1}[a, b]$ is compact cannot be omitted. For example Figure $3.2$ indicates a situation in which this set is not compact. The manifold $M$ does not contain the point $p$. Clearly $M^{a}$ is not a deformation retract of $M^{b}$.

the question is why $f^{-1}[a,b]$ is not compact in the picture and why they are not diffeomorphic.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subset $f^{-1}[a,b]$ is not compact because of the hole at $p$. Arguing with sequences should be enough. The spaces $M^a$ and $M^b$ are not diffeomorphic and $M^a$ not a deformation retract of $M^b$, since they have different fundamental groups. Can you point out why?

Comment: Oh thank you ,I didn't realize that $p$ is removed from the manifold

Comment: @yili Me too at the first time i read it.

Comment: @yili Yes, if we pretend the base of $M^a$ and $M^b$ have a boundary as in the figure.

Comment: $M^a$ has fundamental group $\Bbb{Z}$ and fundamental group for $M^b$ is $\Bbb{Z}*\Bbb{Z}$ correct?